# How to make WPF WebBrowser grow horizontally and vertically?

Tags: wpf, xaml, browser, webbrowser-control, autogrow

In WPF, we are using a WebBrowser control to view HTML content.  When we place the control on our window, it grows horizontally with the window as it grows/shrinks.  However, we have not found a way to make the control grow vertically with the window.  We are looking for some sample code that will allow the WebBrowser WPF control to grow both vertically and horizontally with the window.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With WPF and wanting to grow with the window, the magical starting point is to set the Margin to 0 and avoid setting width and height. (You can have margin equal to another number, but start with zero and see how it looks first!)

Another option is to use a dock panel with last child fill set to true, where the web browser control is the last element (as you read down the page - it doesn't have to be the last element in the rendered UI.